# How to declare a new variable, name it, and initialize this var to the value of different variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, initialization, var

I need to declare a new variable and name it **r4**. Next, initialize **r4** to the value of variable **r1** incremented by **5**. Finally, print the value of **r4**.

**Here is what I have tried so far:**

```
var r4;
r4 = r1;
// trying to use a For Loop. Don't know if it's a right way
  for (r4 = 0; r4 <= r1; r4 = r4 + 5) {
  document.writeln(r4 + "<br/>");
}
```

**And**

Declare a new variable and name it **r5**. Next, initialize the variable to the value of variable **r1** multiplied by **7**. Finally, print the value of **r5**.

**Here is what I have tried so far:**

```
var r5;
r5 = r1;
// trying to use a For Loop. Don't know if it's a right way eather
  for (r5 = 0; r5 <= r1; r5 = r5 * 7) {
  document.writeln(r5 + "<br/>");
}
```

I know that we might don't even need to use a for loop or any loop But I'm really don't know how to make it work as it requested.

I'm new to JavaScript, so don't judge me hard!

Please, advise me how can I solve this two task?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just doing `var r4 = r1 + 5;`?

Comment: At first i thought this is some twelve year old's homework who is completely new to programming and that it was a well formed question. Then i realized the person asking is a college student. Please read a tutorial or beginner's book from start to finish, it will save you and everyone else time - and leave you with a better understanding afterwards.

Comment: @Archer 2 Sorry for the misunderstanding, forgot to mention that this type of solutions var r4 = r1 + 5; or var r5 = r1 * 7; are not acceptable as per instruction, as I've tried that one already. So I was guessing to use a For Loop for increment and multiplying or if-else Statement.

Comment: @connexo  It might be trivial for you but not for everyone DUDE =) And this type of solutions var r4 = r1 + 5; or var r5 = r1 * 7; are not acceptable as per instruction, just for info.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thanks for the suggestion - reading right now! And my apologies for taking your attention and time.

Comment: *And this type of solutions [...] are not acceptable as per instruction, just for info.* **That type is exactly what your task instruction asks for, nothing other.**

Answer (score 3):

#### I need to declare a new variable and name it r4. Next, initialize r4 to the value of variable r1 incremented by 5. Finally, print the value of r4.

```
let r4 = r1 + 5;
console.log(r4);//or whatever printing method you use
```

#### Declare a new variable and name it r5. Next, initialize the variable to the value of variable r1 multiplied by 7. Finally, print the value of r5.

```
let r5 = r1 * 7;
console.log(r5);//or whatever printing method you use (again)
```

Comment: Can whoever downvoted please tell me why?

Comment: Read the question carefully.

Comment: I have. Please tell me why my answer is wrong.

Comment: increment != multiply.  The code in the question (and my comment below the question) shows the first part requires incrementing the value, not multiplying it.  You didn't read it carefully - you skimmed it.

Comment: Ahh. Sorry, didn't notice my own mistake --- edited

Comment: @zevee Thank you for your time and answer really appreciate it! But the problem is that type of answer is not acceptable as per instruction my bad forgot to mention that in question. That why I was trying to use a For loop.

Comment: What instruction? How come it's not acceptable? Post more specific instructions.